# Hibernate: Cannot Fetch Multiple bags

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am getting this error on startup.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contolsEntityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/fmr/config/ControlPersistenceContext.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: controls] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags: [com.mycompany.database.DocumentDetail.documentValidationList, com.mycompany.database.SqlDetail.sqlValidationList]
```

I essentially have a ValidationStep entity, which has a one to one mapping for an SqlDetail or a DocumentDetail.

SqlDetail has a one to many List of SqlValidations

DocumentDetail has a one to many List of DocumentValidations

ValidationStep

```
@Entity
public class ValidationStep {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;



@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name= "automation_information_aId", referencedColumnName= "aId")
private AutomationInformation automationInformation;


private int sequence;

public enum ValidationType {
    Email, Document, Sql, Custom
};

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private ValidationType type;

@OneToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, orphanRemoval = true,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private EmailDetail emailDetail;

@OneToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, orphanRemoval = true,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private DocumentDetail documentDetail;

@OneToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, orphanRemoval = true,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private SqlDetail sqlDetail;

private String description;
```

DocumentDetail

```
@Entity
public class DocumentDetail {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;


//no cascade, a connectionManager save/update cant save/update a  a credential
//unidirectional mapping,
@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name= "credential_id")
private Credential credential;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "documentDetail_id")
private List<DocumentValidation> documentValidationList;

public enum DocumentLocationType {
    Confluence, DocumentCentral, FileShare, OneDrive, SharePoint
};

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private DocumentLocationType locationType;

private String locationUrl;
```

DocumentValidation

```
@Entity
public class DocumentValidation implements Comparable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

//type of validation
public enum DocumentValidationKey {
    NameContains, NameMatchesRegex, LastUpdated, DocumentContains, NameStartsWith, NameEndsWith, DocumentContentsMatchsRegex, NameExactly
}
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private DocumentValidationKey validationType;

//value which results in pass
private String validationValue;
```

SqlDetail is pretty much identical to DocumentDetail and SqlValidation is identical to DocumentValidation

Comment: Try using `Set` rather than `List` for collection type.

Comment: Set is te worst way !
https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-multiplebagfetchexception/